# Creating a new file with selected row data based on a variable column value

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am trying to print out rows in file1 that match data in column 4 of file2 as variable.
The data in file2 is as follows:

```
bb  350     300 350
cc  100     200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600
```

Assume data in file1 is as follows:

```
bb   350    300 350
cc   100    200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
 while read line
    do
      set -- ${line}
      idx="$4"
      z="$2"

    awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '$4 == "$idx" { print $1,$2,$3,$4 }' file1

done < file2
```

The problem is I do not get any output, but when I do for example '$4 == "-2600", it seems to work. It seems it do not accept it as a variable. Kindly assist me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and use proper formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What is the delimiter used in file2?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The delimiter for both files is tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` like below

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4];next}$4 in a' file2 file1
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file1
bb   350    300 350
cc   100    200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600

$ cat file2
bb  350     300 350
cc  100     200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600
```

**Will Produce Output**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4];next}$4 in a' file2 file1
bb   350    300 350
cc   100    200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600
```

**Explanation**

- > `FNR==NR`  If the number of records read so far in the current file
  >   is equal to the number of records read so far across all files,
  >   condition which can only be true for the first file read.
- > `a[$4]` populate array "a" such that the
  >   indexed by the 4th
  >   field, from current record of file2
- > `next` Move on to the next record so we don't do any processing
  >   intended  for records from the second file ( `file1`).
- > `$4 in a` IF the array `a` index constructed from the
  >   field 4 of the current record of file1 exists
  >   in array `a`, we get boolean true, so awk does default operation `print $0` from file1

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well, supposing you would like to use a range of values in a column to do the same operation?

Comment: @eric :  It would be helpful if you can provide input and expected o/p, I did not get the meaning of range of values in a column

Comment: part of file2 data is as follows:
ell ID 0 0 0
 001 000 9000 -1500
 002 000 9000 -1500
 003 500 3000 -1500
MD82 364 4441 -50
MD83 807 1537 -50
 MD84 265 4542 -50
 MD85 667 6072 -50 
19R87 132 6632 900
 19R88 956 6631 900
 19R89 968 3331 900
 19R90 141 3332 900   file1 is as follows:

bb   350    300 350
cc   100    200 100
dd  -100    200 -100
ee  -300    200 -300
ff  -500    200 -500
gg  -700    200 -700
hh  -900    400 -900
ii  -1200   400 -1200
jj  -1600   400 -1600
kk  -2000   400 -2000
ll  -2600   800 -2600

Comment: The following code modified from above is working well but always copy the first line in the file and and so slow. any suggestions on to fix it? awk '
NR==FNR{ range[$4,$5]; next }
FNR==4
{
    for(x in range) {
        split(x, check, SUBSEP); 
        if($4<=check[1] && $4>=check[2]) {if(NR>1) print $0}
    }
}    
' file2 file1